# "(expression) OR (statement)" structure in PHP

Tags: php

I came across the following code

```
defined('CONSTANT') or define('CONSTANT', 'SomeDefaultValue');
```

which I can guess what it does but am not sure since, I could not find this kind of statement structure in the PHP manual.
Is this a shorthand for

```
if (!defined('CONSTANT')) {
  define('CONSTANT', 'SomeDefaultValue');
}
```

Comment: I would not call this a “shorthand” - it is a _similar_ way to achieve the same result, but they are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: _"Furthermore, are there other similar shorthand statements?"_ - There's a ton of useful shorthand statements in PHP. You need to be a bit more specific though. I bet there are a bunch of examples if you do some google search for it.

Comment: _“Furthermore, are there other similar shorthand statements?”_ - not an appropriate question to ask here, IMHO. We are not here to list all the little tricks & tips there might be when it comes to a certain programing language, for you. Go do your own research.

Comment: I did my search (it is not a research matter!), but it is not the conventional way to run a control statement and I could not find it in the php.net manual. I asked to understand how php interpret this statement so that I could understand the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a special statement but an idiom built with other pieces. Just follow the breadcrumbs:

1. [defined()](https://php.net/defined) returns `true` if the constant exists and is defined, `false` otherwise.
2. [or](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) is a good old logical operator, thus short-circuits (evaluation stops as soon as there's an answer).

Comment: It short-circuits when one of the statements retruns true? I mean for example in `(statement1) OR (statement2) OR (statement3)` it executes the statements one by one and as soon as one of them returns true it does not run the rest?

Comment: That's what happens here. With different expressions, different rules will apply.